# Custom csv import using data flow profile not working in magento-1.9.3.1

Tags: import, csv, dataflow, magento1.9.3.1

I want to custom import csv in a model using data flow profile. For that i have followed below steps :

1) Created a `customimport.csv` under `var/import`

2) Under `admin > system >Import/Export > Dataflow - Advanced Profile`, create new profile with **Profile Actions XML**

```
<action type="dataflow/convert_adapter_io" method="load">
    <var name="type">file</var>
    <var name="path">var/import</var>
    <var name="filename"><![CDATA[customimport.csv]]></var>
    <var name="format"><![CDATA[csv]]></var>
</action>

<action type="dataflow/convert_parser_csv" method="parse">
    <var name="delimiter"><![CDATA[,]]></var>
    <var name="enclose"><![CDATA["]]></var>
    <var name="fieldnames">false</var>
    <var name="number_of_records">1</var>
    <var name="adapter">mymodule/convert_adapter_customimport</var>
    <var name="method">saveRow</var>
</action>
```

3) created a module : **app/etc/modules/Bv_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bv_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Bv_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

4) **app/code/local/Bv/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bv_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bv_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <mymodule>
                <class>Bv_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </mymodule>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <convert_adapter_customimport>Bv_Mymodule_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customimport</convert_adapter_customimport>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

5) **app/code/local/Bv/Mymodule/Helper**

```
<?php
class Bv_Mymodule_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

6) **app/code/local/Bv/Mymodule/Model/Convert/Adapter/Customimport.php**

```
<?php

class Bv_Mymodule_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customimport extends Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Abstract
{
    public function load() {
    }

    public function save() {
    }
     public function parse()
    {
        $batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
        $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
        $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();
        foreach ($importIds as $importId){
            $batchImportModel->load($importId);
            $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();
            $this->saveRow($importData);
        }
    }
    public function saveRow(array $importData)
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($importData);exit; 
    }
}
```

7) Now when i run the profile in popup, i get the error :

> Method "saveRow" not defined in adapter dataprofile/convert_adapter_customimport.

[image]

I dnt understand what i'm missing. If anyone can point out.? 
TIA.

Comment: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2385/user-reject-every-2nd-edit-suggestion?cb=1